# Looking for a music organizer, with possible cloud features

Tags: macos, audio, itunes, iphone

I am looking for a music organisation app for a mac with quite specific requirements. I have resorted to a forum after a fair time googling and trying out several apps.

My friend, who is a music teacher, will regularly import tracks, albums, sound effects, key changed duplicates and goodness knows into her iTunes library for work purposes. However, she is getting fed up of work tracks getting mixed in with the tracks she purchases for her personal consumption. As you can imagine, her library is getting slowly out of control.

So, I am looking for an app that will overcome this that she can use for her work stuff. But it should have the following features.

**Must Have**

- Playlist Support (hundreds)
- Add Tracks from iTunes & local folders to playlists
- Ability to convert any files to MP3

**Would Like**

- Sync playlists to iPhone/web interface (dropbox?)
- Share playlists
- Clean modern mac style UI
- Keep track of file-type conversions and file edits

I understand that iTunes does pretty much all of this, but something separate is needed so personal life (iTunes) can be kept separate from her work as much as possible.

Thanks.

Comment: In Super User, and all the StackExchange sites, shopping or product recommendations are considered off topic and open ended, and sometimes even too localized. Try to reword your question in a way that you are not asking for products, but more of processes; this will help keep it on topic

Comment: This question would be a good one for the [Software Recommendations SE site](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Have you though of using two iTunes libraries on the same computer. With this method when you launch iTunes you hold shift (option for mac) while launching iTunes to choose which library you want to use for that particular session.

Comment: Hey. Yep I had already tried that with her, but she would end up opening files in the wrong library and causes more issues that it was worth. Thanks for the suggestion.